# "German is the official language OF/IN Germany..."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I use "of" or "in" in my sentence?

"German is the official language **of/in** Germany, Austria, Belgium, Switzerland, Luxembourg, and Liechtenstein.

Comment: Antonia, whether you use 'of' or 'in', the sentence is not accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article 'the' makes the sentence incorrect. Belgium has three official languages: Dutch, French, and German; Switzerland has four: German, French, Italian and Romansh. Luxembourg has three: French, German, and Luxembourgish. Also, 'of' is the usual preposition for a official aspect of a state (language, capital city, currency, etc).

You can say

> German is **the** official language **of** Germany and Austria, and
> **an** official language of Belgium, Switzerland, Luxembourg, and Liechtenstein.

For completeness, you could include 'the Italian province of Alto Adige (South Tyrol)' in the second group.

Answer (score -1):

Both ‘of’ and ‘in’ the sentence. However, ‘of’ seems more appropriate.

> German is the official language in Germany, Austria, Belgium, Switzerland, Luxembourg and Liechtenstein.

The TOP one is not so appropriate.

Comment: What if I say instead "German is one of the official languages in Germany, Austria, Belgium, Switzerland, Luxembourg and Liechtenstein"?

Comment: Is "in" incorrect?

Comment: Do I have to mention "Germany" in the list of the countries?

Comment: Could you tell me if the rephrased sentence is correct with "the"?  "German is one of the official languages in Germany, Austria, Belgium, Switzerland, Luxembourg and Liechtenstein"?

Comment: @AntoniaA   See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. But why is there the definite article in the first sentence and indefinite in the second?

Comment: Does the number of other languages and the countries where the mentioned language is spoken matter?

Comment: @AntoniaA - there is only one suggested sentence in my answer.

Comment: Is it because Germany and Austria don't have other official languages while the other listed countries have? If a country has only one official language can I also use the indefinite article in my sentence? For example, "German is an official language of Germany and Austria"

Comment: Yes, there is only one sentence but I see different articles.

Comment: It would be wrong to say "German is one of the official languages of Germany", because it would strongly imply that Germany had other official languages.  It would also be odd (but not wrong) to say "German is an official language of Germany", because it would suggest that it had others.  However, when combining multiple countries, you could say "German is an official language of Germany, Austria, Belgium, Switzerland [etc]" (to avoid using both articles), and this would be fine, although Michael's formulation is obviously more accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much!